# Visual Studio 2015 Community - controls get moved when Windows 8.1 app is launched

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I am building a simple Windows Store app in Visual Studio 2015 Community. However, I do struggle with placing controls in Designer. I've created an inner Grid and place my controls in it and Designer-wise it looks fine:
[image]

But when I debug the application and run it full-screen it looks like this:
[image]

I think it has to something to do with resolution and I've checked this - I'm at 1680x1050 right now and the resolution set in *Devices* window is set to 1366x768, so basically same aspect ratio of 16:10. Changing the resolution to other in VS results in even bigger mess.

EDIT: XAML code:

```
<Page
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="IdzNaRyby.MainPage"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:IdzNaRyby"
xmlns:common="using:IdzNaRyby.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
    <x:String x:Key="AppName">My Application</x:String>
</Page.Resources>

<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,59,39,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                    AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                    IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,30,40"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Margin="120,0,60,60" Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="58,60,461,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40">
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="500" FontSize="24"  Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
            <Button x:Name="startButton" Content="Start game" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="20,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Imię" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,25,0,513" Text="Name" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" RenderTransformOrigin="1.585,0.167" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

I still try to solve it and I realized that when I remove the inner Grid and place the controls just on the main Grid eveything works just fine. How's that so?

Thank you very much help.

Comment: consider posting your XAML for a better potential response

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my post.